# How to save data using FileNameSetter or similar

Tags: export, files-and-directories, dialog-window

I would like to export data to a file using a SaveAs type dialog, using something like `FileNameSetter[name,"Save"]` to give a browse button.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. It is very possible that I have simply misunderstood the documentation.

Many thanks,
Christina

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SystemDialogInput["FileSave"]` will do this for you.

Something like

```
fileName = SystemDialogInput["FileSave"]
If[fileName != $Canceled, Export[fileName, myData]]
```

should do the whole trick. The fire extension determines the type of export (if MMA knows it and supports it).

Preselecting a directory path and filtering allowable file extensions can be done as follows:

```
SystemDialogInput["FileSave", 
                  {
                    FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"*.*"}], 
                    {
                      "JPEG" -> {"*.jpg", "*.jpeg"}, 
                      "Portable Network Graphics" -> {"*.PNG"}
                    }
                  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. I found that `Save[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"],data]` allows me to save data to a file.

Comment: @Christina `Save` is fine if you just want to save some Mathematica symbols to be read in again by Mathematica. If you want to save data in a more structured and exchangeable format `Export` is usually the first choice.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It has helped me a lot. I found that I needed to change
"If[fileName != $Canceled, Export[fileName, myData]]"
to
"If[UnsameQ[fileName, $Canceled], Export[fileName, myData]]"
otherwise in case the user rejected the file name I suggested and entered another valid filename, Mma was unable to evaluate the 'If" condition.

Comment: @Simon Glad to be of help. UnsameQ (=!=) is indeed the better choice in many inequalities.