# How do I Export through a standard system file save dialog activated by a Button?

Tags: export, files-and-directories, gui-construction

As near as I can tell, `Export` cannot be configured through arguments or options, to present a standard system file save dialog to the user, so that he can specify a location and name for his file. Instead, it seems to require that these parameters be specified as arguments. [One way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6547/37) around this is to use `SystemDialogInput`

```
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], ...]
```

which works fine in simple cases, but in more complex cases, such as the ones I need it for, this fails silently. In particular, I can't get it to work with `Show`:

```
Manipulate[f = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}], 
 Row[{Button[
    "Export", {Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], Show[f], "PDF"]},
    ImageSize -> 100, Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}]}]]
```

Strangely, this works fine if, instead of using `Export`, a file is specified as an argument.

Why doesn't `Export` + `SystemDialogInput` work with `Show`?

Comment: It works fine for me, it exports a pdf with the plot to desired location. Mathematica 8.0.4.0 linux 64-bit

Comment: @ssch: Fails every time for me: OS X 10.8.2, *Mathematica* 8.0.4.0.

Comment: Works properly on Windows, too. This problem is apparently specific to OS X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I use the option `Method->"Queued"` within `Button`, this works

```
    Button["Export", 
      Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}], 
      "PDF"], Method -> "Queued"]
```

Otherwise, `"Preemptive"` will be the default, making it possible that not enough time is allocated for the `Button` action to complete. See the reference docs on `Button`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be a bug in `Button` that occurs (at least) in *Mathematica* 8.0.4 running on Apple OS X. Here is what I determined. The following expression fails

```
Button["Export", 
   Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "untitled.pdf"],
          "******", "PDF"]]
```

while the following two expression work

```
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "untitled.pdf"], 
       Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}], "PDF"]

Button["Export", 
   Export["/Users/oldmg/Desktop/test.pdf", "******", "PDF"]]
```

So I don't think the problem has anything to do with graphics.

#### Update

Reworking raxacoricofallapatorius' post with david's answer taken into account, I tried

```
Manipulate[f = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}], 
  Button["Export", Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "untitled.pdf"],
                          f, "PDF"], 
         ImageSize -> 100, Method -> "Queued"]]
```

This worked like a charm. Note there is no need to use `Row` or `Show`. Also, adding the second argument, "untitled.pdf", to `SystemDialogInput` makes for a much improved **Save** dialog. I do think it would be a good idea to localize `f` by adding `{f, ControlType->None}` to the `Manipulate`.

There is still a bug in `Export`. If you cancel out the **Save** dialog, you will get an error message that you shouldn't.  This may be OS X specific.